# Can I produce a re-skinned app by copying the Xcode project and renaming it?

Tags: xcode

I have a finished iPhone application, and now I´m going to do another app that is almost exactly the same, but with different background images, data, and name. Now I wonder how I can do this. Can I just copy and paste my project and rename it? Or should I start a new project and drag in my files and create a new storyboard? Can I drag in the storyboard too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

follow me. :)

First if you want to change the project name

[image]

[image]

Rename

[image]

Enable

[image]

======================

if you want to submit your app to appStore you have to add new app with the new name in ituensConnect

=======================

to change Bundel ID change it directly > I use XCode 5

[image]

Comment: And what about the app bundle id?